# How to pass a pointer to the array of structure in another fuction

Tags: c

I am trying to pass pointer to an array of structures to another function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct CovidData{
  char region[7];
  char towns[12];
  char race[12];
  int yearlyIncome;
  int members;
  int testedMembers;
  int testedPositive;
} CovidData;


void RandomDataGenerator(CovidData *data[] ,int count)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){    
          memcpy(data[i]->region,"david",sizeof("david"));
          memcpy(data[i]->towns,"david",sizeof("david"));
          memcpy(data[i]->race,"david",sizeof("david"));
          data[i]->yearlyIncome=1000;
          data[i]->members=99;
          data[i]->testedMembers=88;
          data[i]->testedPositive=656;
    } 
}

int main() {
    struct CovidData data[100];    

    RandomDataGenerator(&data,2);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){    
        printf("%s",data[i].region);    
    }    
}
```

But it throws an error while compiling in terminal with gcc

```
incompatible pointer types passing 'CovidData (*)[100]' to 
parameter of type 'CovidData
```

Comment: you declare 1st argument to function RandomDataGenerator as array of pointers, but call it with an array of elements

Comment: change function signature to RandomDataGenerator(CovidData *data ,int count) and modify all -> operatorss inside function to .

Comment: Re “throws an error”: “Throw” is properly used to refer to some exception (abnormal condition) that causes program control to be transferred to an error-handling routine. When a compiler tells you there is an error in your program, we merely say the compiler reports an error. It does not throw an exception. (Internally, throwing an exception might have been involved in how the compiler handled this, but we do not know, and it is the external behavior of the compiler that is relevant here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to `void RandomDataGenerator(CovidData *data ,int count);` and pass only the pointer to the first array element, like this `RandomDataGenerator(data,2);`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct CovidData{
  char region[7];
  char towns[12];
  char race[12];
  int yearlyIncome;
  int members;
  int testedMembers;
  int testedPositive;
} CovidData;


void RandomDataGenerator(CovidData *data ,int count)
{

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){    
          memcpy(data[i].region,"david",sizeof("david"));
          memcpy(data[i].towns,"david",sizeof("david"));
          memcpy(data[i].race,"david",sizeof("david"));
          (data+i)->yearlyIncome=1000;
          data[i].members=99;
          data[i].testedMembers=88;
          data[i].testedPositive=656;    
    } 

}

int main() {
    struct CovidData data[100];    

    RandomDataGenerator(data,2);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){    
        printf("%s\n",data[i].region);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: `void RandomDataGenerator( const int count, CovidData data[static count] );` --- argument `data` declared like that, is an array of min count element and can not be `NULL`.  Going further, I might be so bold to suggest ["Modern C" by Jens Gustedt](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score 3):

`CovidData *data[]` is grouped as `CovidData *(data[])`, so it declares an array of pointers to `CovidData`. For a pointer to an array, you would use `CovidData (*data)[]`.

However, we rarely pass a pointer to an array. Usually, it is sufficient and convenient merely to pass a pointer to the first element. Thus, you would declare the parameter as `CovidData *data` and pass it as `RandomDataGenerator(data, 2)`.

If you did declare the parameter as a pointer to an array, you would not use it with `data[i]->region`. You would need `*data` to get the array before applying the subscript, and again you would need parentheses for correct grouping: `(*data)[i]->region`.

Comment: We use pointers to arrays very often as per [this post](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dont-use-fake-matrices/), for example. And we never pass arrays to function differently to this: `void my_fun( const int count_, char arr[static count_]) ;`